# Data entry to pandas data frame variable

Tags: python, pandas, key, dataframe

I have below pandas data-frame object. My objective is to use this as a data base to enter data in to each month using command prompt so that the new data entered via command prompt get saved to the data frame variable. For example an operator wanted to enter November data it should get stored to variable df.NOV. However below piece of code copies the single data entry to multiple rows.Is there any solution?. Similarly I am presently using if elif for selecting the variable. But is there any way to use a pointer to select required month directly in data frame?
for example I get a string variable named CM="NOV" in the code. Is there a way to use df.CM to tell python that it has to enter data for November?

```py
for i  in range(len(df)):

    CMR = float(raw_input('CMR FOR '+df.Name[i]+" PLOT - "+df.Plot_NO[i]+ "::OMR= "+str(df.OCT[i])+': '))
    SR=float(df.OCT[i])
    nl=CMR-SR
    print "PHASE     PLOT_NO          PMR  CMR   USAGE (L)"
    print df.Name[i]," | ",df.Plot_NO[i], "  | ",df.OCT[i], " | ", df.SEP[i], " | ",nl
    nd=len(df.ix[i])
    st=nd-6
    xax=range(0,len(df.ix[i][st:nd]))
    for i in range(0,28):
        if CMN == "NOV":
           df.NOV[i]=CMR
           df.NOVWU[i]=nl
        elif CMN == "DEC":
           df.DEC[i]=CMR

        df.to_pickle('pnb_wc_2014.pkl')
        df.to_csv('pnb_wc_2014.csv')

df.ix[1]
Out[14]:

Name      xxxxxxxx 
Phase                I
Plot_NO              2
RSTAT               No
DEC                  0
JAN                  0
FEB                  0
MAR                  0
APR                  0
MAY                  0
JUN                  0
JUL                  0
AUG                  0
SEP                  0
OCT                108
NOV                200
DECE               NaN
JANWU                0
FEBWU                0
MARWU                0
APRWU                0
MAYWU                0
JUNWU                0
JULWU                0
AUGWU                0
SEPWU                0
OCTWU              108
NOVWU            10000
DECWU              NaN
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you post `df.info()` also I'm confused by your structure, it looks like you've put the months as columns rather than say have a month column so when you assign to `df.NOV` it'll assign to all rows the value to the `NOV` column, this doesn't sound like you want this

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3heUQNme7G5UFYxR3Q5MDVNRUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am posting the file link below. It can be loaded to python as pandas.read_pickle(filename)https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3heUQNme7G5UFYxR3Q5MDVNRUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think you need to change your dataframe structure, essentially get rid of the `JAN-DEC` columns, they should really be `MONTH`, then you need to filter on the assignment like so: `df.loc[df.MONTH == 'NOV'] = CMR` or similar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, But in this case how different months data gets stored in different columns?. Is there a concept of sub column or some thing ?

Comment: No you have a month column, the value for the month column will be JAN-DEC

Comment: May I have an example please ?

Comment: Sorry SO is not hear to answer a question that broad, that maybe something appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ I think you need to rethink your data structure, you should be treating your dataframe structure similar to a db table and think about normalising the data, you do not want to store unique values as columns that will inflate your data and make many rows redundant